# How can I make my stored procedure return a non zero if an insert inside of it fails?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_purchase_test
    @AdminTestId int,
    @PurchaseDate DATETIME,
    @UserId int
AS    
INSERT INTO dbo.UserTest
(  
   AdminTestId,
   PurchaseDate,
   UserId,
   Sequence
)           
SELECT  AdminTestId,
        @PurchaseDate,
        @UserId,
        1
FROM    AdminTest       
WHERE   AdminTestId = @AdminTestId    
RETURN 0
```

I have a Unique index on UserTest.AdminTestId and sequence so there is a possibility that this stored 
procedure will not work. How can I make the stored procedure return a non zero if the insert failed?

From what I understand it might be a good idea to use a TRY-CATCH. However if I do this should I do it like this:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT   -1
END CATCH
```

or

```
BEGIN CATCH
    RETURN 99
END CATCH
```

I am confused between a SELECT at the end of a stored procedure and use or RETURN

Here's how I call the stored procedure. Ideally I would like to be able to return an error message from my C# method.

```
        var sql = @"dbo.sp_purchase_test  @AdminTestId,
                                          @PurchaseDate,
                                          @UserId";
        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@AdminTestId", adminTestId),
            new SqlParameter("@PurchaseDate", DateTime.UtcNow),
            new SqlParameter("@UserId", Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()))
        };
        var result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
```

Comment: As a side note [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Comment: use try catch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: Try @@RowCount (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx). See the example at the end.

Comment: If your definition of "fail" is exception(error), use TRY-CATCH but if you mean "now rows inserted" use @@Rowcount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use output parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
@Value1 nvarchar(1),
@Value2 nvarchar(1),
@IsInserted bit output
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
     INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name]
           ([col_1]
           ,[col_2])
     VALUES
           (@Value1,@Value2)
    SET  @IsInserted=1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET  @IsInserted=0
END CATCH

RETURN @IsInserted

END
```

Execute Procedure:

```
DECLARE @IsInserted bit 

EXEC    [dbo].[test]
        @Value1 = N'a',
        @Value2 = N'b',
        @IsInserted = @IsInserted OUTPUT

SELECT  @IsInserted as N'IsInserted'
```